# How can I make my Gridview rows clickable by clicking anywhere on the row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I'm working on a project for college. It's a shop website where customers can place orders.

What I've done so far is populated the Gridview with products by using a linq query.

Now, what I'm having trouble with is that I want to make these rows clickable so that I can execute the gv_SelectedIndexChanged method so I can have a product description appended to a label below.

I also want to be able to pass data to another page relating to the row that's selected when I click a button. I'm reasonably confident I can figure this out though, I've done something similar before.

So my question is how can I make my Gridview rows clickable?

This is the Gridview I have.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:GridView>
```

And this is the code that's populating it.

```
var products = from p in db.ProductTbls
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = p.ProductName,
                           Cost = p.UnitPrice.ToString(),
                           Stock = p.Quantity.ToString()
                       };

        gv.DataSource = products.ToList().Distinct();
        gv.DataBind();
```

I tried using a guide I found online how to do it but I wasn't able to figure out how to get it to work.
[Guide](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Selecting-GridView-Row-by-clicking-anywhere-on-the-Row.aspx)

Comment: check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

@ConorS, I believe the reason why your app is crashing is that you are performing a greedy operation before you perform a Lazy operation. What I mean is that you should perform .Distinct before .ToList().. Thus you should write it as:

```
 gv.DataSource = products.Distinct().ToList();
```

Greedy operations like ToList(), execute Immediately while Operations like .Distinct are Deferred....
 you can find more about the two types [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx)!

Comment: @JonH he Edited the Question, and removed the part where he said his application was crashing. That's what the heck this answer refers to. So please remove the down vote.

Comment: It was crashing because I'm an idiot, haha I forgot to match the column names up so it was throwing an error at me... just a silly mistake.